# How Can I Set The Windows Form Position Manually

Tags: c#

I am developing Desktop application, which loads a Form with different Texts and condition is so When i Click ok Button it shows Texts from the Form one by one

it is working perfectly but the Problem is i have more than one screen and say when i load a form on Current screen and click OK it stays at primary screen which is Ok ,but say when i load my form and drag it to next screen and click ok its comes back again to Primary Screen But i want it to stay on another Screen ...where i drag it into

here is line of code which loads my form

```
if(Form1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
```

// at this line every time i click ok it shows the form but in Primary Screen so is there any solutions i can control the position i mean new position where i grag it into.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `Form.Location` property and `Form.StartPosition` :

// Set the start position of the form to the manual.

```
form1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;

form1.Location = new Point(100, 100);
```

More information :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984420(v=vs.71).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Don't forget `Form1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;` before `ShowDialog()`

Comment: alredy tried this code its not working it means i have tried this code before showdialog(), but again its loaded on Primaryscreen not from secondary monitor where i drag it into..

Answer (score 3):

You need to detemine the available screen first, then set the form's location.

```
var myScreen = Screen.FromControl(this);
var mySecondScreen= Screen.AllScreens.FirstOrDefault(s => !s.Equals(myScreen)) ?? myScreen;

form1.Left = mySecondScreen.Bounds.Left; 
form1.Top = mySecondScreen.Bounds.Top; 
form1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
```