# Two form with the same Location but different Position in the screen

Tags: c#, winforms

I new a form2 in form1, set `form2.Location = form1.Location`. When the program runs, they show on different positions on the screen, but both of their `Location.X` are exactly the same. And there is a 9-pixel difference between the two `X`. It's so weird.

when I set `overlay.Location = new Point(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y + (Height - ClientSize.Height));`
[image]

when I set `overlay.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + 9, this.Location.Y + (Height - ClientSize.Height) - 9);`
[image]

Here's the code.

form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool isOverlayGenerated = false;
    TestForm overlay = new TestForm();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        VisibleChanged += Form1_VisibleChanged;
        overlay.Size = ClientSize;
        overlay.ShowOnMeMo += () =>
        {
            overlay.memoEdit1.EditValue = $"form1: ({Location.X}, {Location.Y})";
            overlay.memoEdit1.EditValue += Environment.NewLine + $"form2: ({overlay.Location.X}, {overlay.Location.Y})";
        };
        overlay.Owner = this;
    }

    private void Form1_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!isOverlayGenerated)
        {
            overlay.Location = new Point(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y + (Height - ClientSize.Height));
            //overlay.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + 9, this.Location.Y + (Height - ClientSize.Height) - 9);
            isOverlayGenerated = true;
            overlay.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

form2

```cs
public partial class TestForm : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
{
    public delegate void DoAThing();
    public event DoAThing ShowOnMeMo;
    public TestForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void simpleButton1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowOnMeMo?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: The coordinates are different because your `overlay` form doesn’t have a nonclient area (you turned-off the system titlebar and window borders). You need to adjust your coordinates to account for that difference. (**do not hardcode the differences** because they vary with each Windows release, instead use GetSystemMetrics: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetrics

Comment: There is a property controlling how form is displayed: `form1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual`, see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31401568/1997232).

Comment: @Dai thanks, that's the right answer. I did find the height of title bar with the para `SM_CYCAPTION` but I couldn't find the width or height of the nonclient after printing all results of `GetSystemMetrics()`. But I did find another way to ensure the right nonclient size by using `Form.Bounds` and `SystemInformation.CaptionHeight`. And I Show the code as the answer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Dai 's answer, I find a way to solve this problem.

```cs
int nonclientWidth = Bounds.Width - ClientSize.Width, nonclientHeight = (Bounds.Height - SystemInformation.CaptionHeight) - ClientSize.Height;
overlay.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + nonclientWidth / 2, this.Location.Y + SystemInformation.CaptionHeight + nonclientHeight / 2);
```